# Should @RequestParam or @RequestBody be used for POST requests in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, http

`@RequestBody` requires that a class be created for the JSON body to deserialize into, while `@RequestParams` do not.

Which one should be used for POST requests, assuming that the params don’t need to be obfuscated? Does it matter? Is either one recommended over the other?

Answer (score 2):

> `@RequestBody` requires that a class be created for the json body to deserialize into

No it doesn't. You can e.g. deserialize into a `Map` or a `List`, depending on the JSON.

> Which one should be used for POST requests?

That depends on the `Content-Type` (mime type) of the request.

> Does it matter?

Yes.

> Is either one recommended over the other?

For mime types `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` you should use [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

For anything else, you need to use [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html).

Answer (score 1):

@RequestParam , you can use when you want to map from the GET/POST request to your method argument and you can set some default value to it in case you are not passing any argument.
@RequestBody, you can use when you are expecting an object as it will automatically deserializes the json into a java type.